# Difference between EC2 "Elastic IP" and "IPv4 Public IP"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to understand the difference between **Elastic IP** and **IPv4 Public IP** that's assigned to an EC2 instance and their significance.

I have been trying to connect to the Internet from an EC2 instance I launched within a new public subnet created within a new VPC. I created a new Internet Gateway, a new route table, a new network ACL, and a new security group and configured them appropriately.

However, I am unable to connect to the Internet from the EC2 instance even though I was able to SSH into it remotely.

Going over Internet forums, I learned that for an EC2 instance to connect to the Internet from a public subnet, the instance should have an Elastic IP. The instance I created has **IPv4 Public IP**, but not **Elastic IP.** Can someone please explain the need for an **Elastic IP**?

Here are the steps to replicate this issue:

1. Create a new VPC (Services -> Networking & Content Delivery -> VPC -> Virtual Private Cloud -> Your VPCs).
   IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.0.0/16.
   Set Edit DNS Hostnames -> Yes.
2. Create a new Subnet (Virtual Private Cloud -> Subnets) in the above VPC.
   IPv4 CIDR: 10.0.0.0/24.
   Set Modify auto-assign IP settings -> Enable auto-assign public IPv4 address.
3. Create a new Internet Gateway (Virtual Private Cloud -> Internet Gateways).
   **Attach to VPC** and select the new VPC.
4. Create a new Route Table (Virtual Private Cloud -> Route Tables) and associate it with the new VPC.
   Routes tab -> Edit -> Add another route -> Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 and Target: above Internet Gateway.
   Subnet Associations -> Associate -> Select the earlier created new Subnet -> Save.
5. Create a new Network ACL (Virtual Private Cloud -> Security -> Network ACLs) and associate it with the new VPC.
   Inbound Rules -> Edit ->
   **Rule # Type        Protocol  Port Range Source    Allow / Deny**
   100    SSH (22)    TCP (6)   22         0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
   200    HTTP (80)   TCP (6)   80         0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW
   300    HTTPS (443) TCP (6)   443        0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

   Outbound Rules -> Edit ->
   **Rule #   Type           Protocol  Port Range  Source    Allow / Deny**
   100      ALL Traffic    ALL       ALL         0.0.0.0/0 ALLOW

   Subnet Associations -> Associate with the new Subnet -> Save
6. Create a new Security Group (Virtual Private Cloud -> Security -> Security Groups) and associate it with the new VPC.
   Inbound Rules -> Edit ->
   **Type        Protocol Port Range Source**
   HTTP (80)   TCP (6)  80         0.0.0.0/0
   SSH (22)    TCP (6)  22         0.0.0.0/0
   HTTPS (443) TCP (6)  443        0.0.0.0/0

   Outbound Rules (No change and as below)
   **Type        Protocol Port Range Source**
   ALL Traffic ALL      ALL        0.0.0.0/0
7. Launch a new Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS EC2 instance.
   Configure Instance -> Network -> New/created VPC
   Configure Instance -> Subnet -> New/created Subnet (auto selected)
   Configure Security Group -> Select an existing security group -> New/created security group -> Review and Launch
   In EC2 instance description, `Elastic IPs` will be blank and `IPv4 Public IP`   will be populated (this difference is what that lead to my question).
8. SSH into the new Ubuntu EC2 instance with login: `ubuntu`
   Run `$ sudo apt-get update` and there is no response.

I am not sure what else needs to be done for the EC2 instance to access the internet or in which step am I making a mistake. As the instance is in the public subnet of VPC, I don't think moving it to a private subnet and connecting via NAT would be a good option. All I want is direct connectivity to the Internet from the EC2 instance.

(Thanks John for the formatting help and everyone who responded)

Comment: "I learned that for an EC2 instance to connect to the internet from a public subnet, the instance should have an Elastic IP" That's not true, it just needs a public IP.

Comment: Does your route table have open access to the outside world? A non-default VPC is private by default, the default VPC is public.

Comment: If you can SSH *into* the instance, then you should be able to access the Internet *from* the Instance. Could you please show your **Outbound Security Group** configuration for the instance?

Comment: Yep, the route table associated with the subnet into which I launched the EC2 instance is connected to an Internet Gateway that I created manually. Here are the route table contents: 
**Destination Target Status Propagated**
10.0.0.0/16 local  Active No
0.0.0.0/0 igw-3610c451 Active No
And, here are the **Outbound** and **Inbound** of the security group:

**Type Protocol Port Range Destination**
All traffic   All  All   0.0.0.0/0

**Type  Protocol Port Range Source**
HTTP  TCP      80         0.0.0.0/0
SSH   TCP      22         0.0.0.0/0
HTTPS TCP      443        0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Sorry, line breaks got stripped in my earlier post..

Comment: The biggest difference between an public AWS Elastic IP Address and an auto-assigned public AWS IP Address is that when the instance is stopped an auto-assigned IP is lost and you won't get it back except by luck. With an Elastic IP Address it stays assigned and the instance always comes back up with the same address. There are other differences due to the ways Amazon charges and manages them. From a networking perspective with respect to accessing the internet etc you will have the same problems and solutions with either of them.

Answer (score 7):

You need an elastic IP if you want to retain the IP after a stop/start. If the instance doesn't have an elastic IP, it will get a new IP after a stop/start.

In your case, you should be able to connect to the internet. Did you modify the default outbound rules of the security group? If not, post the output of `traceroute` or `lft` which will tell where the problem is.

Did you create the VPC manually or using the VPC wizard? If you use the [VPC Wizard](https://us-west-1.console.aws.amazon.com/vpc/home?region=us-west-1#wizardSelector:), everything is setup automatically.

Comment: I created the VPC manually and launched an Ubuntu 16.04 EC2 instance in a new public subnet. Unfortunately, I am not able to use `traceroute` or `lft` as these tools are not installed by default and am unable to update/install packages due to no internet connectivity(`sudo apt-get update` is not working). Yep, EC2 instances via VPC Wizard mode worked fine. However, I would like to have this VPC set up completely manually.

Answer (score 1):

As far as your Question is concerned , there is not much adding a Elastic IP do relative to IpV4 Public IP. At the end , both are IPs only.

Agreed with what mentioned by @helloV

I would suggest you to relook at your bi-directional Internet Gateway Configurations . and read VPC (Internet Gateway Config)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably with the NACL inbound rules. You need to allow for inbound traffic from the ephemeral port range(1024-65535). When you try to connect to a server, the server assumes a port in this range to send the response. Since your NACL wouldn't allow it, it doesn't come back to you.

NACL defaults allow all inbound and outbound traffic. So it works. Your issue is the reverse of what is mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/resolve-connection-sg-acl-inbound/).